# Proof of the inclusion-exclusion principle

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

The inclusion-exclusion principle for $n$ sets is proved by Kenneth Rosen in his textbook on discrete mathematics as follows:

> **THEOREM 1 — THE PRINCIPLE OF INCLUSION-EXCLUSION**   Let $A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_n$ be finite sets. Then
>   $$
> \begin{multline*}
> |A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \cdots \cup A_n| = \sum_{1 \leq i \leq n} |A_i| - \sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} |A_i \cap A_j| \\ + \sum_{1 \leq i < j < k \leq n} |A_i \cap A_j \cap A_k| - \cdots + (-1)^{n+1} |A_1 \cap A_2 \cap \cdots \cap A_n|.
> \end{multline*}
> $$
>   *Proof:* We will prove the formula by showing that an element in the union is counted exactly once by the right-hand side of the equation. Suppose that $a$ is a member of exactly $r$ of the sets $A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_n$, where $1 \leq r \leq n$. This element is counted $\binom{r}{1}$ times by $\sum |A_i|$. It is counted $\binom{r}{2}$ times by $\sum |A_i \cap A_j|$. In general, it is counted $\binom{r}{m}$ times by the summation involving $m$ of the sets $A_i$. Thus, this element is counted exactly
>   $$
> \binom{r}{1} - \binom{r}{2} + \binom{r}{3} - \cdots + (-1)^{r+1} \binom{r}{r}
> $$
>   times by the expression on the right-hand side of this equation. Our goal is to evaluate this quantity. The binomial formula shows that
>   $$
> 0 = (1-1)^r = \binom{r}{0} - \binom{r}{1} + \binom{r}{2} - \cdots + (-1)^r \binom{r}{r}.
> $$
>   Hence
>   $$
> 1 = \binom{r}{0} = \binom{r}{1} - \binom{r}{2} + \binom{r}{3} - \cdots + (-1)^{r+1} \binom{r}{r}.
> $$
>   Therefore, each element in the union is counted exactly once by the expression on the right-hand side of the equation. This proves the principle of inclusion-exclusion.

Although the proof seems very exciting, I am confused because what the author has proved is $1=1$ from the LHS and RHS.

Thus, is this still a valid proof? We need to prove that the total cardinality of LHS is the RHS. The RHS produces a $1$ for each member of the union of the sets.

I think in order to produce the cardinality of the union, an extra
summation sign should be appended before the expression in RHS. Could
someone please clarify?

Comment: Who is the *author*, and what textbook is this taken from?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus discrete Math, Keneth Rosen

Answer (score 5):

Let me slightly rephrase the argument. Let $N_r$ be the number of elements contained in exactly $r$ of the sets $A_1,\ldots,A_n$. Then the left-hand side is
$$
|A_1 \cup \cdots \cup A_n| = \sum_{r=1}^n N_r.
$$
The first sum on the right-hand side is
$$
\sum_{1 \leq i \leq n} |A_i| = \sum_{r=1}^n \binom{r}{1} N_r.
$$
The second sum on the right-hand side is
$$
\sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} |A_i \cap A_j| = \sum_{r=2}^n \binom{r}{2} N_r.
$$
More generally,  the $m$th sum on the right-hand side is
$$
\sum_{1 \leq i_1 < i_2 < \cdots < i_m \leq n} |A_{i_1} \cap A_{i_2} \cap \cdots \cap A_{i_m}| = \sum_{r=m}^n \binom{r}{m} N_r.
$$
Therefore the right-hand side is equal to
$$
\sum_{r=1}^n \binom{r}{1} N_r - \sum_{r=2}^n \binom{r}{2} N_r + \sum_{r=3}^n \binom{r}{3} N_r - \cdots + (-1)^{n+1} \sum_{r=n}^n \binom{r}{n} N_r.
$$
Rearranging, the right-hand side is equal to
$$
\left[ \binom{1}{1} \right] N_1 + \left[ \binom{2}{1} - \binom{2}{2} \right] N_2 + \left[ \binom{3}{1} - \binom{3}{2} + \binom{3}{3} \right] N_3 + \cdots + \\
\left[ \binom{n}{1} - \binom{n}{2} + \binom{n}{3} - \cdots + (-1)^{n+1} \binom{n}{n} \right] N_n.
$$
The coefficient of the general term $N_m$ is
$$
\binom{m}{1} - \binom{m}{2} + \binom{m}{3} - \cdots + (-1)^{m+1} \binom{m}{m}.
$$
By the binomial theorem, this equals $1$, and so the right-hand side equals
$$
1 \cdot N_1 + 1 \cdot N_2 + 1 \cdot N_3 + \cdots + 1 \cdot N_n = \sum_{r=1}^n N_r,
$$
which is exactly the same as the left-hand side.

Comment: Sorry. Do you mean $N_r = |A_r|?$

Comment: I have a bit difficulty comprehending the meaning of $N_r$ here. Thanks for your efforts!

Comment: No, I don't mean $N_r = |A_r|$. Give it a few hours and see if you can decipher my definition of $N_r$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are right that an extra summation needs to be appended to the beginning of both sides to prove the inclusion-exclusion formula.  This can be understood by using indicator functions (also known as characteristic functions), as follows.  Let $U$ be some finite set (the universe), and let $S \subseteq U$.  The indicator function (or characteristic function) of $S$ is the 0,1-valued function $I_S: U \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ on the domain $U$, defined by $I_S(x) = 1$ if $x \in U$, and $I_S(x)=0$ if $x \notin U$. Observe that $|S| = \sum_{x \in U} I_S(x)$.  In other words, the number of elements in $S$ is equal to a sum of $0$'s and $1$'s, where the number of $1$'s is of course the size of $S$.  We are interested in the case where $S = A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \cdots \cup A_n$.

What the proof given in text shows is that the indicator function $I_S$ (where $S = A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \cdots \cup A_n$) is equal to a particular sum of indicator functions (where the subscripts for these latter indicator functions are intersections of the $A_i$'s).  More specifically, it is proved that
$$I_{A_1 \cup \cdots \cup A_n} = (I_{A_1} + \cdots + I_{A_n} )  - (I_{A_1 \cap A_2} + \cdots + \cdots I_{A_{n-1} \cap A_n}) + (I_{A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3} + \cdots )+ \cdots + (-1)^n I_{A_1 \cap \cdots \cap A_n}.$$
This formula holds because, as you show, if an element $x \in U$ appears in exactly $r$ of the $A_i$'s for some $r \ge 1$, then the LHS indicator function trivially evaluates to $1$, and the RHS sum of indicator functions also evaluates to $1$ (by the binomial formula). Similarly, both sides evaluate to $0$ if $r=0$ (i.e. if $x \in U, x \notin S$).  Thus, the two 0,1-valued functions are equal, meaning the two functions take the same value for each $x$ in the domain $U$.  This means the many terms in RHS sum cancel out to give either a $0$ or a $1$, for any $x \in U$ that you pick.

If two functions $f, g$ on domain $U$ are equal, i.e. if $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x \in U$, then the summations $\sum_{x \in U} f(x)$ and $\sum_{x \in U} g(x)$ are also equal.  So, take the summation of the LHS indicator function's values over $x \in U$, and similarly for the RHS.   Recall that for any set $X \subseteq U$, we have $\sum_{x \in U} I_X(u) = |X|$.  So, for the left hand side,  the sum $\sum_{x \in U} I_{A_1 \cup \cdots \cup A_n}(x)$ evaluates to $|A_1 \cup \cdots \cup A_n|$.  For the right hand side, we are taking the sum of all those indicator functions over $x \in U$.  Use the fact that $\sum_{x \in U} I_{A_i}(x) = |A_i|$, that $\sum_{x \in U} I_{A_1 \cap A_2}(x) = |A_1 \cap A_2|$ (by taking $X = A_1 \cap A_2$), and so on, to get the inclusion-exclusion formula.